# memory-leak happens when running on physical iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-leaks

When testing my app, everything runs fine on the iOS simulator, but I experience memory leaks when running the same app on a physical iOS device. I am new to developing iOS apps and I know that are many potential reasons for this. I want to know why things are different between the simulator and a physical device and if there is a way to solve my memory leak issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you go through the tutorial below. It will help you a lot to understand how to debug your memory problems and other issues.

---

1. [My App Crashed – Now What? 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)
2. [My App Crashed – Now What? 2/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10505/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-2)

hint: your problem can be solved with zombie objects; but I advise you to follow the tutorials first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that you have a leak in your device and not in the simulator. How did you conclude that? Both could be leaking, but the problem is just being manifested differently on the different platforms or simply encountering the problem more quickly on the device than the simulator.

If you have a leak, I'd suggest two things:

1. Run your code through the static analyzer (select "Analyze" from the "Product" menu in Xcode). Newer developers tend to ignore this incredibly useful tool. I know that I finally mastered my Objective C memory management techniques only after going through the analyzer results and really understanding (and resolving) each and every issue in a really big project I had. Anyway, if you're getting any warnings there, you really should fix them, as they're often indications of memory management problems.
2. Run the program through the profiler. See the [Finding Leaks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001883-CJBJFIDD) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference (sometimes an annoying large one) between the simulator and the device. This is because the underlying hardware of each is quite different. Obviously the simulator is *simulating* the iOS hardware, but that doesn't make it foolproof. With certain APIs and frameworks, things may ONLY work on the hardware, and sometimes bugs will occur on the hardware that didn't occur on the simulator. Just think of it as the "adventure" of iOS development.

As for resources, I'd take a look at @Arab_Geek's links, and also Apple's [Tools for iOS Development](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/URL_Tools_for_iPhone_OS_Development/_index.html) - specifically [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652), like Leaks.